# When using Access Tokens, how do you handle when a user first arrives to your page? (NodeJS, JWT)

Tags: node.js, jwt, token, access-token

I have set-up a basic site using nodejs and and jwt access tokens.  Everything works fine but I'm having trouble working out the flow when a user first comes to the site.  With cookies you already have that data stored in the browser so you can know if a user is logged in upon arrival and can route them accordingly.  But with JWT tokens it's different.  When someone types in URL and the request hits the server it doesn't have that access token until the page is returned and you retrieve the token.

I have some ideas of what I can do, but I want to make sure I'm doing it properly.  What is the proper way to handle this?  Is it simply to return the page, retrieve the accesstoken then make another ajax call to the server to verify the token and then route them accordingly?  That seems like the logical solution, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: That's correct or you put your jwt in a cookie but that defeats the purpose. Basically your first page just has nothing but logic to send the jwt to your server.

Comment: Thanks! This might sound silly but when the page first returns since there is no access token i do an ajax call back to that same route with the access token but when i try to return the page after token verifcation it's returned in XHR form and doesn't render.  i'm using nodejs w/ express, by the way.